# MVC3 Database entities don't get initialized as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

after carefully researching for a solution to this strange problem that I have and accomplished nothing. I am pretty much desperated.

I am working on a MVC3 project.

I have a DB Context class like this:

```
//SpaceUpEntities.cs
public class SpaceUpEntities: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Profile> Profiles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Venue> Venues { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Capacity> Capacities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<VenueStatus> VenueStatuses { get; set; } 
}
```

and I initialize DBContext when application start

```
//Global.asax.cs
 protected void Application_Start()
 {
        Database.SetInitializer<SpaceUpEntities>(null);  
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        RegisterDependencyInjection();
        ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new TrimModelBinder();
 }
```

The problem occurs when I want to query/Insert/Update to the DB.
For example this piece of code

```
 //SecurityRepository.cs 
    public RegisterFeedback Register(User user, Profile profile)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var entities = new SpaceUpEntities())
            {  
                // Check existing email address
                var emailExisted = entities.Users.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Email == user.Email);
                //... So on 
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.Error(e);
            return new RegisterFeedback(false, Messages.GeneralError);
        }
    }
```

After `using (var entities = new SpaceUpEntities())` entities should have been initialized but I ended up with this error

[image: Error]

Error Message:

> Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation
>   timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function
>   evaluation.

Initially, I thought it was a connection problem to my server, so I checked:

1. ConnectionString
2. SQL Server setting (SQL Server 2012)

Although I can hardly see why they are the cause of this problem since I took serveral methods to test my ConnectionString to find it has no issue.

Any help would certainly be appreciated. 
Thank you in advance.

Thang Do

P/S: this is how I tested my connection string:
This is my connection string
    
        
      
I tested it with this 
[image: ConnectionTest.udl]

Comment: Can you confirm that your tables have been created in the database and have been seeded with data?

Comment: Table is definitely created. there are sample data in the db.

Comment: It's not clear from your screenshot what the error is but by doing `Database.SetInitializer<SpaceUpEntities>(null);` you are turning off the database initialiser.

Comment: Tools -> Options Debugging Uncheck "Enable property evaluation and other implicit function calls" then see if you get any error

Comment: @Zaki: I still get the same error after unchecking that option

Comment: @BenRobinson: how so? null parameter means no strategy needed for the initialization. am I right?

Comment: @ThangDo No strategy means "don't initialise the database", this is how you turn initialisation off. If you don't set it to null it will use the default which I think is CreateDatabaseIfNotExists, if you want a different strategy then set it to the appropriate one.

Comment: I tried with CreateDatabaseIfNotExists, but it didn't work. Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<SpaceUpEntities>());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are using the Initialization strategy which matches what you are trying to achieve.  `Database.SetInitializer<T>(...);`

By having the line below in your `App_Start` method, I believe you may be bypassing initialization

```
Database.SetInitializer<SpaceUpEntities>(null);
```

Here are some options from an [article](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx) on code first database initialization strategies that I hope will be helpful to you:

---

There are four different database Initialization strategies:

1. **CreateDatabaseIfNotExists**: This is default initializer. As name suggests, it will create the database if none exists as per the configuration. However, if you change the model class and then run the application with this initializer, then it will throw an exception.
2. **DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges**: This initializer drops an existing database and creates a new database, if your model classes (entity classes) have been changed. So you don’t have to worry about maintaining your database schema, when your model classes change.
3. **DropCreateDatabaseAlways**: As the name suggests, this initializer drops an existing database every time you run the application, irrespective of whether your model classes have changed or not. This will be useful, when you want fresh database, every time you run the application, while you are developing the application.
4. **Custom DB Initializer**: You can also create your own custom initializer, if any of the above don't satisfy your requirements or you want to do some other process that initializes the database using above initializer

Comment: I have error even before I get a chance to make any changes to the DB.

Comment: Which initialization are you looking for? if you mean the DBContext, then I believe I have it at Global.asax.cs. otherwise, I have no idea and could use some pointers

Comment: I mean are you actually seeding the database with rows or are you just creating the tables according to the SpaceUpEntities datacontext object?  With LINQ, you can't always inspect the intermediary objects in a way you might expect if they are lazy loaded.

Do you get an actual exception thrown or are you just inspecting the object while debugging?

Comment: I get exception at this point 'var emailExisted = entities.Users.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Email == user.Email);' and then I debug to see those error messages

Comment: Try updating your initialization like this instead of setting it to null like you have.  Use this instead

Database.SetInitializer<SpaceUpEntities>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<SpaceUpEntities>());

Comment: You may find this article helpful http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: If you drop the database before running the MVC app (back up first if necessary) and then run it, is it re-created as expected with seeded data?

Comment: I tried it again with SetInitializer and it works this time. I guess the last time failed because I didn't clean + rebuild the project, perhaps? I'll take a few test rounds and see if it really works and mark your answer then. Really appreciate your help, Chris

Comment: Glad your SO amigos were able to get you pointed back in the right direction!